# Другая запись условия if

Tags: ruby

Есть код, разничия только в 1 классе, интересно как записать через `условие ? значение1 : значение2` , чтобы менялся только один класс `green на orange`

```
<% if @c_type == 1 %>
    <nav class="track-menu green">
<% else %>
    <nav class="track-menu orange">
<% end %>
```

Comment: Такая запись называется "тернарный оператор".

[Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Это,не дает ответ на мой вопрос. И сам вопрос бы не в этом

Comment: [enSo, ruby - тернарный оператор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: @Dmig топикастер знает, что такое тренарный оператор. Вопрос же не в том, как он записывается в руби, а в том, как его применить в конкретной ситуации.

Comment: @PashaPash, я так и понял; но подумал, что данная мною информация поможет, ибо в вопросе словосочетание "тренарный оператор" не присутствует.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос решил так `<nav class="track-menu <%= @c_type == 1 ? 'green' : 'orange' %>">` не думал,что в ruby так можно менять стили

Comment: С помощью ERB так можно менять любой текст, не только стили. :)